# Adding an incremental count of sub-groups using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

If I have a grouping:

```
 mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,carb)
```

How can I add a column that counts the number of unique group combinations; so `carb` groups within `cyl` groups? This would be something like:

```
cyl carb combination
6     2    1
6     4    2
6     6    3
4     2    1
4     4    2
4     6    3
```

Comment: Do you need `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, carb) %>% mutate(count = row_number())` or is it `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, carb) %>% summarise(count = n())`.  Is the expected output correct?

Comment: I think my original question was ambiguous. I have tried to make it clearer! Sorry about that

Comment: May be `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(carb = n_distinct(carb))`, but still not clear with the expected if it is not correct

Comment: Instead of `This would be something like:`, can you please add the exact expected output

Comment: I think you need something like `mtcars %>% 
  distinct(cyl, carb) %>%
  arrange(cyl, carb) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(comb = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a better way to avoid the n column, but below should be a good start:

```
mtcars %>% count(cyl,carb) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(combination=1:n()) 
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl  carb     n combination
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>       <int>
1     4     1     5           1
2     4     2     6           2
3     6     1     2           1
4     6     4     4           2
5     6     6     1           3
6     8     2     4           1
7     8     3     3           2
8     8     4     6           3
9     8     8     1           4
```

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to do this, this is the way I did it:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,carb) %>% summarize("count" = length(carb))
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output given by the OP.